# How to have nested base.html in django's templates?

Tags: django, django-templates

I am rebuilding all my templates so it becomes a lot more manageable and custom, the tree would look like this :

```
├───core
│   └───templates
│       └───base.html (original, touches every page)
│   ...   
│
├───app1
│   └───templates
│       ├───base.html (extends from core/base.html, only touches app1)
│       └───file1.html (extends from app1/base.html)
│   ...
│
└───app2
    └───templates
        ├───base.html (extends from core/base.html, only touches app2)
        └───file2.html (extends from app2/base.html)
    ...
```

To connect `app1`'s template to `core`'s I use `{% extends '../../core/templates/base.html' %}`, in the core app there'll be `{% block container %}{% endblock %}` as example and in app1, app2 there'll be other `{% block other_content %}{% endblock %}` blocks. as you can see blocks are nested too.

*The issue is that I get this error :*

> The relative path ''../../core/templates/base.html'' points outside the file hierarchy that template 'base.html' is in.

**Question:**  I was wondering what was the best approach to resolve this issue without hardcoding it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original `base.html` had conflicts with others of his kind, so I renamed `app1`, `app2`'s base to `base[app_name].html` which resolved my issue. The tree would look like this :

```
├───core
│   └───templates
│       └───base.html (original, touches every page)
│   ...   
│
├───app1
│   └───templates
│       ├───base_app1.html (extends from core/base.html, only touches app1)
│       └───file1.html (extends from app1/base_app1.html)
│   ...
│
└───app2
    └───templates
        ├───base_app2.html (extends from core/base.html, only touches app2)
        └───file2.html (extends from app2/base_app2.html)
    ...
```

No need to hardcode the path either : `{% extends 'base.html' %}` is enough and `{% extends 'base_[app_name].html' %}` for files within the app's template.